# Python hex editor/editing component

Tags: python, hex-editors

I am looking for a hex editor or a hex editing component written in Python. So far, the only thing I have come up with is [YaHEbwinPy](http://homepage.hispeed.ch/py430/python/index.html), but it crashes with "pure virtual function call" 
upon exit when I finally got it to run.

Comment: have you installed the stand alone version or have you downloaded the source code? it sounds like something that could be potentially easily solved, at worst you should contact the author for a bug report.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried [PSPad](http://www.pspad.com/)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I think your suggestion would be applicable in places where the link is for a *document*, not a software. There would be no point explaining the software here, right?

Comment: I don't agree (and neither do the moderator guidelines); context for links is always advised. Even mentioning what "PSPad" is, how it's relevant, or how it'll help solve the problem helps. I see a text editor; what's that got to do with a hex-editor or hex-editor component implemented in Python?

Comment: I see your point.. I will update it soon

Comment: Is it in Python or in Borland Delphi (as author mentions on about page)?